# App is not launching silently on background after change in location significantly

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, background-process

We are working on an app which needs location subsequently on terminated state. I am trying to achieve this by enabling **Background Modes** services i.e `location update` and `background fetch`, but app doesn't relaunch silently after a significant change in location. I have Enabled properties like `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` and `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` with my location manager on **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** and on `didUpdateLocations` create `CLRegion` and enable locationManager `startMonitoring(for: region)` but all this doesn't works.

**This is what I have written in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
  if application.applicationState == .active {
            LocationManager.shared.startMonitoringLocation()
        }


            // When there is a significant changes of the location,
            // The key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey will be returned from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
            // When the app is receiving the key, it must reinitiate the locationManager and get
            // the latest location updates

            // This UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey key enables the location update even when
            // the app has been killed/terminated (Not in th background) by iOS or the user.

            if launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.location] != nil {
                //You have a location when app is in killed/ not running state
                LocationManager.shared.afterResume = true
                LocationManager.shared.startMonitoringLocation()
                LocationManager.shared.addApplicationStatus(toPList: "APP relaunch silently")
            }
```

**Location Manager**

```
  func startMonitoringLocation() {
        if (anotherLocationManager != nil) {
            anotherLocationManager!.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        }
        anotherLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
        anotherLocationManager!.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        anotherLocationManager!.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        anotherLocationManager?.delegate = self
        anotherLocationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        anotherLocationManager?.activityType = .otherNavigation

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
            case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
              print("No access")
            case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
                print("Access")
            }
        } else {
            anotherLocationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            print("Location services are not enabled")
        }
        anotherLocationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }
```

The problem is control doesn't come into this code snippet.

```
 if launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.location] != nil {
                //You have a location when app is in killed/ not running state
            }
```

Comment: Do you have "always" location permission?  Where do you set up the location manager if you don't get the location launch option key?  How are you terminating the app for testing?  What options are you setting on your location manager?  You cannot rely on `applicationWillTerminate` executing

Comment: @Paulw11

Question 1 - Yes, "location permission" is "always". 

Question 2 - Firstly when App Launch incase of active state. We initiate location manager with request for location permissions and set it `locationManager` properties like, `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates`, `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically`,`kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` , `otherNavigation`, `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`.

Question 3 - Terminate app through multitask window using Home button on iPhone 8 Plus.

Comment: Do you have real always permission or only provisional always permission on iOS 13?

Comment: @Paulw11
I marked "location always" through app when it request for permission and later marked `Always` through  Settings -> App -> Location.

I think it's real always permission.